# Take too long Hidden/Post FX/Uber Shader in post processing plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, uber-api, post-processing

2D project (Unity 2018.3.0)

1. I download the plugin of Unity Post Procesing
2. Add to the camera the script
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzJmi.jpg
3. Configurate only Color Grading
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCLSI.jpg
4. Try to build and it takes too long cause appear in the charge bar Shaders.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/e51q1.jpg

Any solution here?

Comment: Well, you added a Plug-in -> it appears to contain some shaders -> build will take longer than before.

Comment: but i talk with people and that's to much shaders and i think I'm not using it so i want a tip to reduce it or delete.I don't know. I'm in 2D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Go to Assets->PostProcessing->Resources->Shaders
2. Find "Uber" and open the code.
3. At the first lines of the script do you going to see this:

   ```
   #pragma multi_compile __ UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA
   #pragma multi_compile __ CHROMATIC_ABERRATION
   #pragma multi_compile __ DEPTH_OF_FIELD DEPTH_OF_FIELD_COC_VIEW
   #pragma multi_compile __ BLOOM BLOOM_LENS_DIRT
   #pragma multi_compile __ COLOR_GRADING COLOR_GRADING_LOG_VIEW
   #pragma multi_compile __ USER_LUT
   #pragma multi_compile __ GRAIN
   #pragma multi_compile __ VIGNETTE_CLASSIC VIGNETTE_MASKED
   #pragma multi_compile __ DITHERING
   ```
4. Change "#pragma" for "#define" and only stay in pragma if you are going to use this process

In my case I'm only using ColorGrading

```
#define  multi_compile __ UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA
    #define  multi_compile __ CHROMATIC_ABERRATION
    #define  multi_compile __ DEPTH_OF_FIELD DEPTH_OF_FIELD_COC_VIEW
    #define  multi_compile __ BLOOM BLOOM_LENS_DIRT
    #pragma multi_compile __ COLOR_GRADING COLOR_GRADING_LOG_VIEW
    #define  multi_compile __ USER_LUT
    #define  multi_compile __ GRAIN
    #define  multi_compile __ VIGNETTE_CLASSIC VIGNETTE_MASKED
    #define  multi_compile __ DITHERING
```

Comment: This gave me errors all over the place. Idk what to do

Answer (score 1):

It is taking long to compile because the uber shader has a metric fuckton of multi_compiles in it. The amount of shader variants is 2^(number of multi_compiles).

You can reduce the number of variants by manually editing the ubershader and remove some multi_compile lines which refer to features you don't use.

[Here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/PostProcessing/blob/v1/PostProcessing/Resources/Shaders/Uber.shader#L22...L29) is an example of some lines you can comment out.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: it goes a little bit faster,but not what i expect,but ty!

Comment: I'm afraid that's the only way of affecting the build speed. If you comment out all except the COLOR_GRADING line, there should only be about 4 variants remaining. You can also replace "#pragma multi_compile __ SOME_FEATURE" with just "#define SOME FEATURE" if you want to leave it permanently enabled.

Comment: omg i think that worked,i need to do more tests and come to post it,ty!!!!

Comment: Consider marking this post as an answer if it solved your problem.